# ssh a CentOS machine installed in VMWare in different machine

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, putty, vmware

I have installed a Centos7 in VMWare WorkStation in my wife's laptop and we can use putty to login in to the machine and access it from my wife's laptop.

I am trying to access the CentOs7 from putty in my laptop and its is not connecting.  Getting timeout when I try to ping the IP address of the Centos Machine.

Below are the steps I tried.

- Checked the ssh server status in Centos Machine and its running.
- Generated ssh keys in my laptop and added the pub key to `authorized_keys`

What are the other steps I need to do in order to connect the remote machine running in VMWare in different Machine ?

Comment: Verify both machines are on the same subnet.

Comment: @Ramhound we both connected to same wifi network but different subnet mask. How to change that ?

Comment: Configure the subnet of the VM to be the same as the host

Comment: what if my wife's laptop connected to different network? will it still possible to ssh the machine in the VM ?

Comment: You made absolutely no mention of that in your question

Comment: You will need to have everything on the same network or at least have some kind of connections between networks. In case you have everything at home just on separate networks, you can try configuring routes between networks. In case it is in separate locations, you can try configuring VPN.